# Can I install GNU/Linux in text mode on android?

Tags: linux, motorola-moto-g, ssh

I want to use my old smartphone (Moto 3G) like Rassbery Pi to make some low level things with just terminal. I  want to install GNU/Linux in text mode, get access to it with SSH, get connection to Internet and have possibility to type in installed system with onscreen keyboard like in android.

Important thing is that, I want to FULLY remove android and install GNU/Linux in this place. I don't care about SMS, Phone calls etc. ( But things like camera handling, and way to see battery status, playing/recording sounds, or changing screen brightness of the screen are nice to have).

Is there any distribution that can satisfy me? And how can I install chosen system instead of android?

EDIT:
I am seraching for way to install TEXT ONLY operating system. This question [Dual booting linux on android galaxy note 10.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47712/dual-booting-linux-on-android-galaxy-note-10-1) doesn't help me because I am trying to just make Rassbery Pi clone from my old phone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95316/discussion-on-question-by-dolidod-teethtard-can-i-install-gnu-linux-in-text-mode).