# is it possible to install linux on android?

Tags: linux, operating-system

Is it possible to install open-source Linux distribution like Ubuntu on Android Device?

If so, how would this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you searched this stackexchange, and found the questions there with previous answers lacking detail for you? What previous steps have you considered? Can you be specific which ones or which steps are failing?

Comment: i would recommend app Linux Deploy and don't remove android, or look for Ubuntu Touch from UBports https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95316/2019/6/24 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213910

Comment: @wbogacz Tried [AndroNix - Linux on Android without root](https://andronix.app/) but it consumes a lot of memory. ANd poor documentation

Comment: Would like to explore other methods with root & without root

Comment: @Pluviophile you cannot natively boot Linux on Android device (see [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526)). But you can run in `chroot` (if device is rooted) or `proot` environment. There are plenty of apps which rely on either of both phenomenon, but in my experience using apps adds to your trouble. Just learn how to use `chroot` (it's very simple because it's same on any Linux environment) and run it yourself on `adb` or Terminal Emulator app or as `init` service or remotely e.g. on `ssh`. It works for any Linux distro.