# How to use Alcatel Download Mode

Tags: alcatel

I found this mode on my onetouch 9022x tablet but I don't know how to use it. Are there any tutorial how to use it?

Comment: [MSM8909](https://androidmtk.com/use-qpst-flash-tool) or [MT8127](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool) or do you mean [fastboot](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands) mode? https://androidmtk.com/alcatel-mobile-upgrade-tool

Comment: I mean fastboot mode

Comment: there is not much you can do from fastboot. you can unlock bootloader, flash or format partitions, and maybe some oem commands like charging behavior

Comment: I want to try install linux so I need to unlock bootloader but I don't know how to do it

Comment: you can't install linux. except someone has built linux especially for onetouch 9022x (link)? but still it will destroy your tablet if you don't know it's qualcomm or mediatek

Comment: I'll try to make my linux

Comment: do you know any phone model that runs linux? can you name the distribution please?

Comment: [pinephone](https://www.pine64.org/pinephone/)

Comment: [pinephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PinePhone) is a special hardware allow booting from SD Card. it's especially made for this purpose. It comes with it's own [bootloader](https://xnux.eu/p-boot). It's like you code your own [BIOS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220677) from scratch. original release was with [Ubuntu Touch](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213910) which was a linux-look-like on top of android kernel supported quite few devices (I tested on Nexus 4) can't speak for Pine but surely it will never run on your Alcatel, because it only runs on Allwinner SoC